# Python Google Cloud Storage Image Store

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Ok...I have been trying to figure out how to do this for a long time no without much success.
I have a Python Script locally on Google App Engine Launcher that receives a image file via post. I have not launched application yet, however I am able to get to the Google Cloud SQL so I assume I can get to Google Cloud Storage.

```
import MySQLdb
import logging
import webapp2
import json

class PostTest(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        image = self.request.POST.get('file'))
        logging.info("Pic: %s" % self.request.POST.get('file'))

#################################
#Main Portion
#################################
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', PostTest)
    ], debug=True)
```

The logging outputs this, so I know it is receiving the image:

```
INFO 2014-08-04 23:20:43,299 posttest.py:21] Pic Bytes: FieldStorage(u'file', u'tmp.jpg')
```

1. Do I connect to GoogleCloudStorage
2. How do I upload this image to my GoogleCloudStorage bucket called 'app'?
3. How do I retrieve it once it is there?

Should be a simple thing to do, however I haven't been able to find good/clear documentation on how to do this. There is REST API which is depreciated and the GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient confuses me.

Can someone help me please with a code example? I will be really grateful!

Comment: Example code: https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9541133

Comment: Voscausa - THANKS SO MUCH! I have question though....I implemented your code and got a but changed my default bucket name to 'app' which is my bucket on GCS. I got a "GCS Filename: /app/tmp.jpg" when I ran the code, but the file is not in my GCS Bucket. The read is returning '/_ah/gcs/app/tmp.jpg'. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can read in the example code doc: The serving url in the SDK will look like: other:  https://localhost:8080/_ah/gcs/bucket_name/file_name

Comment: Is there a way to get to a "online" bucket from the SDK?

Comment: Yes, use the GAE production url's like: https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name/file_name You can also use a image serving url, but they cannot be created in the SDK.

Comment: I am so sorry, but I don't understand what I need to change in the code to get this to work with my bucket on GCS. I am very new to this. Would you mind explaining more?

Answer (score 0):

I created a repository with a script to do this simply: `https://github.com/itsdeka/python-google-cloud-storage`

Example of integration with DJango:

```
picture = request.FILES.get('picture', None)
file_name = 'test'
directory = 'myfolder'
format = '.jpg'

GoogleCloudStorageUtil.uploadMediaObject(file=picture,file_name=file_name,directory=directory,format=format)
```

Tip: it automatically creates a folder called 'myfolder' in your bucket if that folder doesn't exist

The link of all pictures uploaded in your bucket is the same except for the file name, so it is pretty easy retrieve the picture that you want.